# Using Excel Validation Formula in several worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using a validation formula to validate a value in a cell based on value of another cell. I want to use the same validation formula in all sheets, but Excel automatically adds sheet name to the formula and hence I have to copy it and make a formula for each page. At the moment, I have something like this:

For BBBank worksheet:

```
=IF(BBBank!O3="Immobilien";SubKat_Immo;IF(BBBank!O3="Privat";SubKat_Privat;SubKat_Bank))
```

and for ING-DiBa worksheet:

```
=IF('ING-DiBa'!O3="Immobilien";SubKat_Immo;IF('ING-DiBa'!O3="Privat";SubKat_Privat;SubKat_Bank))
```

but I wish is something like this for all worksheets:

```
=IF(O3="Immobilien";SubKat_Immo;IF(O3="Privat";SubKat_Privat;SubKat_Bank))
```

Is there any solution to obtain this?

Comment: You can copy and paste the third formula to all sheets that you want to have the same validation, and then Excel will always add the worksheet name in front of the formula after the validation ruling is set up.

Comment: @TerryW At the moment, I am doing so, but I though maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Excel only adds the sheetn name to a referenced range if you move from one sheet to another. The formula you suggested can be copied/pasted throughout the different sheets. You may need to copy the formula text from the address field (or whatever that field is called where you see your formula. This can also be accessed by pressing `F2` when on the formula-cell) and paste into the address field of the next sheet.